# Why my query using timestamp doesn't work in Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I have created a table called myalarmTable with a timestamp datatype for one of the columns. I am testing the query below in Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service OCI console.Somehow, it is not retrieving any record.

```
SELECT alarminfo, alarmtimestamp FROM myalarmtable where alarmtimestamp ="2021-02-24T13:19:00.00000Z"
```

What's wrong with my query?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the string that you are supplying into a timestamp datatype, otherwise, the query runtime thinks that it is a string.  Try the following:
SELECT alarminfo, alarmtimestamp FROM myalarmtable where alarmtimestamp =cast("2021-02-24T13:19:00.00000Z" as timestamp(0))